# Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" in kafka stream?

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, slf4j, apache-kafka-streams

I am implementing apache kafka stream application program in Java inside GCP machine. I am  using kafka version 2.12
Reference URL - 
https://kafka.apache.org/22/documentation/streams/tutorial

Here I am able to setup maven project. then I am able to see tree structure of stream.example in my kafka directory.In the next step, I am trying to execute Pipe java class But here I got stuck in this step.
I am able to execute mvn clean package which is giving Build success.
next command is mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=myapps.Pipe which is giving warning and got stuck... see attached screenshot.[image: kafka mvn command error screenshot]

Here we can see my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>streams.examples</groupId>
<artifactId>streams.examples</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Kafka Streams Quickstart :: Java</name>

<properties>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <kafka.version>2.2.0</kafka.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<!--
            Execute "mvn clean package -Pbuild-jar"
            to build a jar file out of this project!
    -->

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>  
             <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                     <dependency>
                         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                         <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                         <version>1.7.25</version>
                     </dependency>
                     <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tycho-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
                        <version>0.21.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.4,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>single</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore/>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[3.1,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore/>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Apache Kafka dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

First refer to the following link for more clarity.

[StaticLogBinder](https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder)

To Quote, it says

> This warning message is reported when the
>   org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class could not be loaded into
>   memory. This happens when no appropriate SLF4J binding could be found
>   on the class path. Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar
>   slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or
>   logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem.

As part of solution, I will suggest you to use logback.

In maven pom.xml, add the following dependency.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.26</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Create a logback.xml file and put it inside your project src/main/resources

If you do not want to use logback, then simply add the following dependency along with slf4j api.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.26</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```